# Volume buttons stay pressed

Tags: volume-control

If I try to turn the volume on my laptop up/down/mute, it is always like I kept the button pressed. I believe I have to change something in `/lib/udev/hwdb.d/60-keyboard.hwdb`, but I don't know what.

I have a medion laptop

```
System Information
    Manufacturer: Medion
    Product Name: P6669 MD60147
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have the same issue on a Medion P6689 MD61019 and it also exist on Medion E6246 MD63200 for example. You were on the right track; this seemed to do the trick:

Create a text file containing:

```
# Fix for volume keys on Medion keyboards
evdev:atkbd:dmi:bvn*:bvr*:svnMEDION:pn*:pvr*
evdev:atkbd:dmi:bvn*:bvr*:svnMedion:pn*:pvr*
 KEYBOARD_KEY_a0=!mute
 KEYBOARD_KEY_ae=!volumedown
 KEYBOARD_KEY_b0=!volumeup
```

Save it to `/lib/udev/hwdb.d/99-keyboard-medion-vol-fix.hwdb` and run the following commands as root:

```
systemd-hwdb update
udevadm trigger --verbose --sysname-match="event*"
```

and done!  Volume keys now work normally.

**Note:** Since it appears to have no side effect (since this Patch is only applied by people affected), the `:pn*` field is not limiting it to any model. Though it can be easily changed to match only a few models, by specifying their product number.
(You may want to check `/sys/class/dmi/id/modalias` for your specific vendor ID and product number.)

---

From /lib/udev/hwdb.d/60-keyboard.hwdb:

```
# Supported hardware matches are:
...
#  - AT keyboard DMI data matches:
#      evdev:atkbd:dmi:bvn*:bvr*:bd*:svn<vendor>:pn<product>:pvr*
#    <vendor> and <product> are the firmware-provided strings
#    exported by the kernel DMI modalias, see /sys/class/dmi/id/modalias
...
# An '!' as the first character of the key identifier string
# will add the scan code to the AT keyboard's list of scan codes
# where the driver will synthesize a release event and not expect
# it to be generated by the hardware.
...
# To update this file, create a new file
#   /etc/udev/hwdb.d/70-keyboard.hwdb
# and add your rules there. To load the new rules execute (as root):
#   systemd-hwdb update
#   udevadm trigger /dev/input/eventXX
# where /dev/input/eventXX is the keyboard in question. If in
# doubt, simply reload all input rules
#   udevadm trigger --verbose --sysname-match="event*"
...
# Akoya
evdev:atkbd:dmi:bvn*:bvr*:svnMEDION*:pnS3409*:pvr*
evdev:atkbd:dmi:bvn*:bvr*:svnMedion*:pnAkoya*:pvr*
 KEYBOARD_KEY_a0=!mute
 KEYBOARD_KEY_ae=!volumedown
 KEYBOARD_KEY_b0=!volumeup
 KEYBOARD_KEY_19=!p
 KEYBOARD_KEY_df=sleep
```

In short, some Medion laptop keyboards need a `!` for the volume keys (and maybe also the `p` key, whatever it is) because they don't generate key release events; however, not all Medion models are covered by default in /lib/udev/hwdb.d/60-keyboard.hwdb.

Strangely enough, after this fix, pressing and holding the volume keys DOES auto-repeat them until you release the key.

Comment: thank you very much. I will try that as soon as my laptop gets back from the service

Comment: Firstly I got my laptop back from service, secondly your fix works like a charme, which makes me even happier